# facebook openid provider

Tags: facebook, openid

I'm using my Google Username and password as Open-ID to get logged into my own website. Instead of using google i need to login using my facebook username and password as Open-ID. See this link twiki.org/cgi-bin/view/Codev/OpenIDProviderList , it gives me the Open-ID endpoint for corresponding providers. Due to my research i got that facebook doesn't've endpoint. It has an unique way to implement Open-ID concept. Plz help me to reach my goal.

Comment: Is it possible using my facebook username and password to login to my website? I'm using DotNetOpenAuth dll and C# codes.

Answer (score 0):

Facebook cannot be used as an OpenID but,

According to [DotNetOpenAuth](https://dotnetopenauth.uservoice.com/forums/14800-general/suggestions/678767-oauth-2-0-support) Facebook login support via OAuth 2.0 is included in DotNetOpenAuth v4.0 and above.

> Facebook Connect now uses OAuth 2.0, which DotNetOpenAuth will support.
>   https://dotnetopenauth.uservoice.com/forums/14800-general/suggestions/678767-oauth-2-0-support The CTP for OAuth 2.0 includes a Facebook login sample.